# how to generate random number for inserted row sql

Tags: sql

i tried below code but its not inserting...where i made error.can anyone help me...

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(5)
SELECT @str= Product_Name
FROM tb_new_purchase
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Product_Name FROM tb_new_product_Name_id where    
tb_new_product_Name_id.Product_Name=tb_new_purchase.Product_Name )

DECLARE @key VARCHAR(5), @i int
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(120)
SET @i = 1
WHILE @i > 0
BEGIN
SET @key = (SELECT ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 467) + 1000)
SET @i = (SELECT count(*) FROM tb_new_product_Name_id WHERE Product_Id = @key)
END
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO tb_new_product_Name_id (Product_Name,Product_Id)      
VALUES          ('+@str+','+@key+');'
exec(@query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semicolon (`;`) is not part of the SQL syntax (it's a terminator character some tools use) - just remove it from the line you create `@query`:

```
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO tb_new_product_Name_id (Product_Name,Product_Id) VALUES ('+@str+','+@key+')'
```

Comment: For SQL server the semicolon will be required in the future. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx

Comment: Try to declare a `delimiter` that is not `;`